# My responsive web site doesn't work on mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm learning the basics of HTML, CSS and responsive. I've set the @media queries for mobile, but it doesn't work.

But if I open the web site from Desktop (Chrome) and I try to resize the window, it works.

HTML

```
<html>

    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

<body>

    <div class="div1">
        <p class="txt">dig</p>
        <p class="test">- DIG</p>
        <div class="we"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="div2">
        <p class="txt">dig</p>
        <p class="test">Magni</p>
        <div class="we"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="div3">
        <p class="txt">dig</p>
        <p class="test">Grillo</p>
        <div class="we"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.div1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 33.3%;
    background-color: darkgrey;
     float:left;
}

/*.we {
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    margin-left: 165px;
}*/

.div2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 33.3%;
    background-color: darkslategray;
    float:left;
}

.div3 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 33.3%;
    background-color: darkorange;
    float:left;
}

.txt {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 100;
    padding-top: 50%;
}

.test {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50;
    color: antiquewhite;
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

@media screen  
  and (max-width: 320px)
  and (orientation: portrait)  {

    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .div1 {
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: darkgrey;

}

     .div2 {
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: darkslategrey;

}

     .div3 {
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: darkorange;

}

    .txt {
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        font-size: 50;
        padding-top: 25%;
}

    .test {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 25;
        color: antiquewhite;

}

}
```

If you want to test it you can go on: sinh.altervista.org

How can I fix it? And what are the real media queries for every device? On the net I've found a lot of different @media queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify how your document should be rendered with a `meta` tag `viewport` inside of `head` tag.

for example:

```
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3, user-scalable=yes, minimal-ui">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">    
  </head>
```

**Note**: The above example is exhaustive, in your case `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` should suffice but could add these properties if you want to manage zoom, user-scaling, etc...

`width=device-width` does:

> This means that the browser will (probably) render the width of the
>   page at the width of its own screen.

taken from here : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

and `initial-scale=1` will leave the zoom at a ratio of 1

From the draft of the W3C, here are the properties to the `content` attribute you can use : https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#meta-properties.

And some more documentation from MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag